# How to hide Intro/Index Page in TOC of Jupyterbook?

Tags: jupyter, jupyterbook

The Documentation of Jupyter Book is **not showing** the Intro/Index Page in the TOC on the left sidebar. That's what I want for my book.

The Documentation does not explain how to do this. Does anyone know?

[Jupyterbook: Structure the Table of Content](https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/structure/toc.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `_config.yml` file, you should add the following entry:

```
html:
  home_page_in_navbar: false  # Whether to include your home page in the left Navigation Bar
```

You can see the full configuration file and its defaults in the JupyterBook documentation:

- https://jupyterbook.org/en/stable/customize/config.html

Comment: Should be marked as answer!